# Sigma-field on $\Bbb R$ generated by $[0,2]$ and $[1,3]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Let $\Omega = \mathbb R$ $A = [0,2]$, $B=[1,3]$. I need to describe $\sigma[A,B]$.

I know this set will be formed by taking any finite number of intersections, unions and complements of $A,B$ since it's a $\sigma$ algebra. Does that mean $\sigma[A,B] = \mathbb R = \Omega$?

EDIT: So $\sigma[A,B]$ will just be a collection of subsets. It must contain the empty set. It must also contain $\Omega$. It must contain $[0,2]$ and $[1,3]$ as well. It must also contain their intersection $[1,2]$. It must also contain all their complements so $(-\infty,0) \cup (2,\infty)$. Is this better?

Comment: Food for thought: does $\sigma[A,B]$ contain the element $-1$?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$, not a subset of $\Omega$ itself.

Comment: @DavidGao Bear with me. I know I am being stupid. I will take a think and re-edit my question.

Comment: @DavidGao Please check my edit.

Comment: @Dam This is certainly better, but not correct. For example, the complement of $B$ should be in the $\sigma$-algebra, as should the complement of $[1, 2]$. None of these are in your description yet.

Comment: @Dam In general, if you want to consider the $\sigma$-algebra generated by finitely many sets, you should write down the partition generated by these finitely many sets. The $\sigma$-algebra then contains all unions of some parts of the partition. (Hint: in this case the partition has four sets in it, so the $\sigma$-algebra contains $2^4 = 16$ sets.)

Comment: @DavidGao $100$ percent I agree, I know I didn't list everything it was just getting a bit long. I will work using what you said to finish it off. Thank you.

Comment: @AnneBauval I usually prefer not to flag a question for being a duplicate to a closed question with few answers because 1) it can no longer get any answers and 2) if that post was from a long time ago, then the answerer might not answer comments on clarifying what the answer means.

Comment: For the health of this site, duplicates must  be linked to older similar posts, which can still get new answers, and comments to those.